# How to write HTML tags in Perl using LibXML

Tags: html, perl, libxml2

I'm using LibXML to read/write an Android strings.xml file. Sometimes, I need to write html elements such as `<b>` or `<i>`. I've tried doing something like this (for example):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

#
# Create a simple XML document
#

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $doc = XML::LibXML::Document->new('1.0', 'utf-8');

my $root = $doc->createElement("resources");
my $tag = $doc->createElement("string");
$tag->setAttribute('name'=>'no_messages');
$tag->appendText("You have <b>no</b> messages");
$root->appendChild($tag);

$doc->setDocumentElement($root);
print $doc->toString();
```

But I end up with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="no_messages">You have &lt;b&gt;no&lt;/b&gt; messages</string>
</resources>
```

And what I'm looking for is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="no_messages">You have <b>no</b> messages</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`XML::LibXML::Element`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::LibXML::Element) objects have an `appendWellBalancedChunk` method that does exactly what you are asking for.

Here's a demonstration, based on your own sample code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $doc = XML::LibXML::Document->new(qw/ 1.0 utf-8 /);

my $root = $doc->createElement('resources');

my $tag = $doc->createElement('string');
$tag->setAttribute(name => 'no_messages');
$tag->appendWellBalancedChunk('You have <b>no</b> messages');

$root->appendChild($tag);

$doc->setDocumentElement($root);

print $doc->toString;
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources><string name="no_messages">You have <b>no</b> messages</string></resources>
```

Comment: do you know if it's possible to tell appendWellBalancedChunk not to convert HTML entities (such as '&#8211;')? I'd like to write '97&#8211;2004' , but when I do that, I end up with the UTF8 version '97-2004'

Comment: If after writing the XML, I open the file using a standard filehandle, and rewrite all the lines using 'decode_entities' it works as expected. But I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Since it doesn't support `innerHTML`, you have to manually add text and tags:

```
my $tag = $doc->createElement("string");
$tag->setAttribute('name'=>'no_messages');
$tag->appendText("You have ");
$b = $doc->createElement("b");
$b->appendText("no");
$tag->appendChild("b");
$tag->appendText(" messages");
```

That, or use the [parser](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Parser.pod).